# How to show alert in server side javascript on conditional basis?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am using server side Javascript and fetching a column from data extension. I want to show alert on the basis of value retrieved from SSJS lookup but whenever i place alert in SSJS code i get 500 error.

Please help.

Comment: You need to attach more details on your use case and if possible some kind of code you tried out. Maybe this will help to understand your case. Maybe you even try to invoke an alert on the server side, we do not know this if you give to little information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Cloudpage, I would typically suggest using Write() instead of alerts.
I'll assume you did this, otherwise you wouldn't see a 500 error.

`Write(output);`

or in case you do not have a string in your output variable,

`Write(Stringify(output));`

If you are testing something inside SSJS Script activities in automation studio, then Write() does nothing, in this case log errors into a DE.
here I use one with Name

DataExtension_Name

and fields:
ID (primary key), Message

```
var logId = (new Date()).getTime();
var logBuffer = "";

logDE.Rows.Add({ID: logId});

function debug(output) {
    logBuffer = logBuffer + output;
    logDE.Rows.Update({Message: logBuffer},["ID"],[logId]);
}
```